# Apple Diagnostics is not launching on startup - Mac with Intel processor

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, monterey, macos, apple-diagnostics

#### Expected

Launch [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) during the system startup by holding the `D` key as outlined by the Apple support guide for Macs with Intel processors.

#### Observed

The system does not launch Apple Diagnostics and continues to the normal login window.

#### Configuration

- Machine: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019)
- Operating system: macOS Monterey Version 12.5
- Enabled

  - [FileVault](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837)
  - [Firmware password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198#firmwarepassword)
  - VPN

#### Potential solutions

Attempted to press and hold different combinations of `D`

- `command` + `D`
- `shift` + `D`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the firmware password and repeat your test.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455

Comment: Apple Diagnostics works as expected after disabling the Firmware password. Much appreciated!

Comment: Wonderful @AdamHurwitz some people don’t realize diagnostics is another OS different from the one they lock with a firmware password. This will surely help others that face this down the road.

Comment: After your solution I noticed the [Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) mentions disabling the firmware password under "Learn more" at the bottom. Disabling the firmware password is also required for [resetting NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).